# Detect unmapped columns in CsvHelper

Tags: .net, csvhelper

How can i detect that a header column is used in a CSV file that is not mapped in the class that is used for parsing the file with the .NET CsvHelper library.

Example:

```
public class Test
{
    [Name("test1")]
    public string Test1 { get; set; }
    [Name("test2")]
    public string Test2 { get; set; }
    [Name("test3")]
    public string Test3 { get; set; }
}
```

Csvfile:

test1,test2,test3,test4
1,2,3,4

When i parse this file with CsvHelper no exception is thrown although the CSV file contains an undefined column.

Comment: I believe this is an open feature request. Currently it only throws an error if you are missing a column in your CSV file that is mapped in your class. https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/1032

Comment: Ah thanks. Was searching for a similar requirement but missed this one. Will program the header check myself and remove it when this check is available in the interface.